# Python scraper that gets product information from e-commerce website

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, python-requests

I have built a scraper that scrapes data from e-commerce website and saves it to json using my own module. Although, I made the scraper multi-threaded, it starts slow, then speeds up and uses a lot of cpu, after collecting 3000 items (not all the products in the website) it quits. It is working, but I feel like I have messed up the multi-threading, how may I improve it to be fast, and not to quit unwillingly?

```
from task2.files import File
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

BASEURL = 'https://www.motomoto.lt'
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(BASEURL, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

item_list = []

def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
        parse_category(soup, executor)

def parse_category(soup, executor):
    executor.map(
        lambda url: parse_subcategory(url, executor),
        [BASEURL + a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='subcategory-name', href=True)])

def parse_subcategory(url, executor):
    subcategoryPage = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(subcategoryPage.content, 'html.parser')
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as new_executor:
        new_executor.map(
            lambda url: parse_products(url, new_executor),
            [BASEURL + a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='subcategory-image', href=True)]
        )

def parse_products(url, executor):
    productsPage = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(productsPage.content, 'html.parser')
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as newer_executor:
        newer_executor.map(
            parse_item,
            [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='thumbnail product-thumbnail', href=True)])
            
        
        this = soup.find('a', attrs={'class':'next'}, href=True)
        if this is not None:
            nextpage = BASEURL + this['href']
            print('-' * 70)
            parse_products(nextpage)
            
        
def parse_item(url):
    itemPage = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(itemPage.content, 'html.parser')
    title = get_title(soup)
    price = get_price(soup)
    category = get_category(soup)
    
    item = {
        'Title': title,
        'Price': price,
        'Category': category
    }   

    item_list.append(item)
    print(item)

    f = File()
    f.savedata(item_list, filename='output_nothread.json')

def get_title(soup):
    title = soup.find('h1', class_='h1')
    title_value = title.string
    title_string = title_value.strip()
    return title_string

def get_price(soup):
    price = soup.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'price'}).string.strip()
    return price

def get_category(soup):
    category = soup.find_all("li", attrs={'itemprop':'itemListElement'})[1].find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'name'}).getText()
    return category

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "quit unwillingly"?

Comment: Exit the scraper before scraping the whole webpage :)

Comment: That seems to counter your claim that "it is working". This might still be reviewable, but suggesting fixes for that kind of problem is out of scope for Code Review.

Comment: Do you have an error message of some sort when the program unexpectedly exits? You might want to add some error handling to make the program more robust but also debug more easily. Second suggestion is to log activity to a file using the `logger` module, so you can review what happened. The problem may be logical ie the implementation of the recursive crawling, but this is hard to tell if you don't trace the activity of the program.